# Matlab - displaying an object on a graph

Tags: matlab, graph, printing, timer, display

I have a function for a timer as follows

```
HH = 0; MM = 0; SS = 0;
timer = sprintf('%02d:%02d:%02d',HH,MM,SS);
for p = 1:86400
    SS = SS + 1;
    if SS == 60
        MM = MM + 1;
        SS = 0;
        pause(0.01)
    end
    if MM == 60
        HH = HH + 1;
        MM = 0;
        pause(0.1)
    end
    HH;
end
disp(timer)
```

How can i get this to display on a graph while constantly updating. Have not been able to get it to work using the plot() or set() function.

Comment: so do you want the timer value get update continuously, then what is your graph type?Is it generated for plotting a graph or you just want to display the time value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to adjust the particulars of this example based on how you want the timer to look, and notice that I just put a `pause(0.1)` for each second of the clock, so you can watch it faster than real time as indicated in your example.  You can also adjust the size/color of the clock with different arguments to the `text()` function.

```
f = figure;
HH = 0; MM = 0; SS = 0;
timer = sprintf('%02d:%02d:%02d',HH,MM,SS);
text(0.5,0.5,timer);  %% adjust location of clock in graph using the first two arguments: (x,y) coordinates

for p = 1:86400
    SS = SS + 1;
    pause(0.1);  %% pause a fixed amount for each clock tick
    if SS == 60
        MM = MM + 1;
        SS = 0;
    end
    if MM == 60
        HH = HH + 1;
        MM = 0;
    end
    timer = sprintf('%02d:%02d:%02d',HH,MM,SS);  %% construct time string after all adjustments to HH, MM, SS
    clf;  %% clear previous clock display
    text(0.5,0.5,timer);   %% re-plot time to figure        
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, when i run your function it raises an error that the text(0.5,0.5,timer); subcript indices must be real positive integers or logicals. Tried modifying this to many different things, but still raising the same error or that index exceeds matrix dimensions.

Comment: Solved ~ forgot to clear variables from last script.

Comment: What version of MATLAB are you using?   That sounds like you may have accidentally defined "text" as an array...I would try `clear all` and then run it again.